# Can I setup LVM raid1 to mirror one physical disk onto another?

Tags: linux, raid, lvm, raid-1, nixos

I have two HDDs, I'm planning on only using one (with NixOS) and the other one should be a mirrored backup, I've had many problems trying to set up a RAID 1 with NixOS and the only documentation I can find on Raid is the one on LVM so I'm trying it out.

Since LVM seems to only deal with volume groups and those aren't attached to any particular disk or partition is it possible to set it up in a way that it copies the way a "typical" raid 1 setup works?

Comment: AFAIK `mdadm` can create a "typical" RAID 1. With the old metadata format [one could even simply mount any of the drives without `mdadm`](https://superuser.com/a/1288489/432690), metadata was at the end. With the new metadata format this is no longer straightforwardly possible because metadata is in the beginning. Still I believe one can mount the underlying filesystem by finding the right offset. This is not an answer because it's not about LVM and you explicitly asked about LVM.

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski I tried with mdadm but there were problems when it came to the installation for NixOS. Thanks though!

Answer (score 0):

LVM2 supports multiple raid levels. Red Hat has a good [page](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/8/html/configuring_and_managing_logical_volumes/configuring-raid-logical-volumes_configuring-and-managing-logical-volumes) documenting the options and giving an example.

Summarizing the page from Red Hat, create the lv with

```
# pvcreate /dev/sda1
# pvcreate /dev/sdb1
# vgcreate vgraid /dev/sda1 /dev/sb1
# lvcreate --type raid1 -m 1 -l 100%FREE -n lvraid vgraid
```

Confirm that the LV has segments exclusively on one physical disk

```
# lvs -a -o name,copy_percent,devices vgraid
```

I hope this helps. If it answers your question, please consider marking the answer as accepted so it will turn up more easily in searches.

Comment: Yes, I'm looking to make a raid 1 and make LVM use both of my HDDs separately like a "typical" raid 1 would, but since LVM deals in logical volumes rather than in physical disk I'm looking for a way to make LVM put the mirror on sdb and my main on sda

Comment: @okaz Which is exactly what the linked page describes. Create a single VG containing both disks. The create an LV with the `--type raid1 -m 1` options. The LV will be logically split into two segments, one on each physical disk. FYI, mirrored disks do not have "main" vs. "mirrored" disks. All volumes in the mirror are treated identically.

Comment: @okaz My comment above is not exactly accurate. LVM raid volumes do allow you to modify the raid set to designate on volume as slower than another so reads will come preferentially from the faster volume. Other tunings are also possible. These settings are not possible in md arrays or in any physical raid card I'm familiar with.

Comment: I've read the linked page before but I didn't understand that it would automatically separate the disks, I thought it would just distribute the data into the VG. Thanks for the clarification

Comment: when I input the last command in the nix installer I have the following error :
raid1: Required device-mapper target(s) not detected in your kernel.
I've tried installing kmod-dm-raid but it's not part of the nix environment and I can't find another solution